# MVC3 Web Project Error: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.10.0.1:3128"

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I published my MVC3 web project to Azure. When I tried to authorize with fb, I get an error below.

Additional info:

- callbackUrl = http://site.azurewebsites.net/Facebook/AddSocialAccount
- аuthenticateUrl = https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=***&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.azurewebsites.net%2FFacebook%2FAddSocialAccount&scope=publish_stream%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday

so the app authorizes on fb, goes to AddSocialAccount action and fails int the string:

```
var profile = this.Provider.GetUserProfile(code);
```

where goes to:

```
protected override Task<AccessGrant> PostForAccessGrantAsync(string accessTokenUrl, NameValueCollection request)
    {
        return this.RestTemplate.PostForObjectAsync<NameValueCollection>(accessTokenUrl, request)
            .ContinueWith<AccessGrant>(task =>
            {
                string expires = task.Result["expires"];
                return new AccessGrant(task.Result["access_token"], null, null, expires != null ? new Nullable<int>(Int32.Parse(expires)) : null);
            });
    }
```

and string with error is

```
string expires = task.Result["expires"];
```

Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
enter code here
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.10.0.1:3128
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.10.0.1:3128
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.10.0.1:3128]
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6462061
System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +271
[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +2233126
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
Spring.Http.Client.WebClientHttpRequest.ExecuteRequestCallback(IAsyncResult result) in f:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SPRNETREST-RELEASE-JOB1\src\Spring.Rest\Http\Client\WebClientHttpRequest.cs:246
[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3548265
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +73
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +10486829
Project.Social.Facebook.Api.Impl.FacebookOAuth2Template.<PostForAccessGrantAsync>b__0(Task`1 task) in D:\Code\Poll\Project.Social\Facebook\Api\Impl\FacebookOAuth2Template.cs:23
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() +81
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +49

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]   
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3548265
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +73
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +10486829
Project.Social.Base.OAuth2SocialProvider`4.SetAccessToken(String code) in    D:\Code\Poll\Project.Social\Base\OAuth2SocialProvider.cs:49
Project.Social.Base.OAuth2SocialProvider`4.GetServiceClient(String oauth_verifier) in D:\Code\Poll\Project.Social\Base\OAuth2SocialProvider.cs:66
Project.Social.Facebook.FacebookProvider.GetUserProfile(String oauth_verifier) in D:\Code\Poll\Project.Social\Facebook\FacebookProvider.cs:26   Project.Areas.FrontEnd.Controllers.ControllersBase.OAuthControllerBase`3.AddSocialAccount(String code, String oauth_verifier) in D:\Code\Poll\Project\Areas\FrontEnd\Controllers\ControllersBase\OAuthControllerBase.cs:112
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +214
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +91
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +48
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

When I use local computer with connectionString of Azure I don't get this error(I change the domain and url on fb).
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Maybe i should try authorize with fb sdk and don't use the Spring.Net

Comment: I am thinking about the access to 10.10.0.1:3128. How can I change the firewall to this port on Azure?(not cloud service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem. There was the default proxy in my web.config.

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://10.10.0.1:3128" bypassonlocal="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

I removed it. And authorization works correct.